# x minus x is not 0 in R

Tags: r, fft, difference, complex-numbers

this is the first time I'm asking a question here, so i hope you'll understand my problem.

The Thing is, that I want to do my own fft(), without using the given one in R. 
So far it works well for a series like seq(1,5).

But for c(1,1) something strange happen. As far as I could point it out it seems that x - x is not 0 in that case.
Here the lines of code:

```
    series <- c(1,1)                  # defining the Serie
        nr_samples <- length(series)      # getting the length

#################
# Calculating the harmonic frequncy
#################

        harmonic <- seq(0,(nr_samples-1))
        harmonic <- 2*pi*harmonic
        harmonic <- harmonic/nr_samples

#################
# Exponential funktion needed for summing up
#################

        exponential <- function(index, omega){

          result <- exp(-((0+1i)*omega*index))

          return(result)

        }

#################
# The sum for calculating the fft
#################

        my_fft <- function(time_series, omega){

          nr_samples <- length(time_series)
          summand <- 0

   # In the next loop the mistakes Happens       
   # While running this loop for harmonic[2]
   # the rseult should be 0 because
   # summand = - exp_factor
   # The result for summand + exp_factor 
   # is 0-1.22464679914735e-16i

     for (i in 1:nr_samples){

            exp_factor <- exponential((i-1), omega)            
            summand <- summand + time_series[i]*exp_factor     
            print(paste("Summand", summand, "Exp", exp_factor))
          }                                                    

          return(summand)                                      
        }


    transform <- sapply(harmonic, function(x){my_fft(series,x)})
    fft_transform <- fft(series)
    df <- data.frame(transform, fft_transform)
    print(df)
```

Could anyone tell me, why summand + exp_factor, for harmonic[2] is not zero??

Answer (score 3):

This is commonly referred to [FAQ 7.31](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) which says:

> The only numbers that can be represented exactly in R’s numeric type are integers and fractions whose denominator is a power of 2. Other numbers have to be rounded to (typically) 53 binary digits accuracy. As a result, two floating point numbers will not reliably be equal unless they have been computed by the same algorithm, and not always even then. For example

```
R> a <- sqrt(2)
R> a * a == 2
[1] FALSE
R> a * a - 2
[1] 4.440892e-16
```

> The function all.equal() compares two objects using a numeric tolerance of .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5. If you want much greater accuracy than this you will need to consider error propagation carefully.
>
> For more information, see e.g. David Goldberg (1991), “What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic”, ACM Computing Surveys, 23/1, 5–48, also available via http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf.
>
> To quote from “The Elements of Programming Style” by Kernighan and Plauger:
>
> 10.0 times 0.1 is hardly ever 1.0.

(End of quote)

The Goldberg paper is legendary, and you may want to read it. This is a property of *all floating point computation* and not specific to R.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, think that should help a lot.